# Behavior of Part inside Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The following gives some strange "Part" warnings

```
Clear[f];
f = Function[{x}, x[[1]] == x[[2]]]
```

However if I execute the second line again, it works without warnings, any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure? I don't see any warnings in version 7.0.1:

```
In[1]:= Clear[f];
        f=Function[{x},x[[1]]==x[[2]]]

Out[2]= Function[{x},x[[1]]==x[[2]]]
```

Comment: @Yaroslav Works for me too in 7.0.0

Comment: Hm...can't reproduce this after restarting kernel, strange

Comment: @Yaro There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,
Than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

Comment: Yeah. Also "Part" seems special. For instance it gives warning for Part[x,y] instead of quietly leaving it unevaluated like other Mathematica functions

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: If you don't want the assignment to f to try to evaluate the RHS (and thus to try to pick out the first and second parts of the symbol "x"), then use delayed assignment.  f := Function[{x},x[[1]]==x[[2]]] .

Comment: That sometimes is suboptimal...for instance, recently I needed a function F[g] which takes a graph g and returns a function f where f[x] tells you if x is a proper coloring (ie, x[[i]]!=x[[j]] for all (i,j) in the original graph). Since f[x] is called many times, I didn't want g->edges conversion to be run every time, but that required partial evaluation of f's body, hence Part warnings. There might be some hacks to get around it, but for now I just do Off[Part]

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: I usually approach that problem with the same technique necessary to get FindRoot[] to not generate endless warnings: define your function to only work on arguments of the correct head, e.g. f[x_?NumericQ], so that the attempt at symbolic evaluation is not performed.

Comment: The problem comes when trying to programmatically create unevaluated expressions involving Part. For instance, to take {1,2} and return a function of x that returns true if x[[1]]==x[[2]]. There are probably tricks to get around it (http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/index.html), but it's an uphill battle

Comment: @Yaroslav `With[{i = 1, j = 2}, Function[{x}, x[[i]] == x[[j]]]]` =)

Comment: Well, that works when you can enter {1,2} by hand, but a more realistic example would be to create f[x_] which gives True iff x[[i]]==x[[j]] for some pair of adjacent nodes i,j in RobertsonGraph

Comment: Heh, might be time to break this off as a new question, but how about `f[edges_] := Function[{x}, Or @@ ((Equal @@ x /@ #) & /@ edges)]` or `g[edges_] := Block[{x}, With[{ors = Or @@ ((Equal @@ x /@ #) & /@ edges)}, Function[{x}, ors]]]`

Comment: ... and then look at `f[GraphData["RobertsonGraph", "EdgeIndices"]]` or `g[GraphData["RobertsonGraph", "EdgeIndices"]]`. Is that what you mean? Not sure I'm understanding the issue...