# Programmatically creating multivariate functions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This is a split from discussion on [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093657/behavior-of-part-inside-function) question.

Suppose I need to define a function f which checks if given labeling of a graph is a proper coloring. In other words, we have an integer assigned to every node and no two adjacent nodes get the same answer. For instance, for {"Path",3}, f[{1,2,3}] returns True and f[{1,1,2}] returns False. How would I go about creating such a function for arbitrary graph?

The following does essentially what I need, but generates Part warnings.

```
g[edges_] := Function @@ {{x}, And @@ (x[[First[#]]] != x[[Last[#]]] & /@ edges)}
f = g[GraphData[{"Path", 3}, "EdgeIndices"]];
f[{1, 2, 1}]==False
```

This is a toy instance problem I regularly come across -- I need to programmatically create a multivariate function f, and end up with either 1) part warning 2) deferring evaluation of g until evaluation of f

Comment: so you have 2 questions (1) how to create a function which takes a vector argument and manipulates it with Part[], and avoid errors arising when Part tries to deconstruct an undefined symbol, and (2) how to remember evaluations of the function so that they don't need to be recomputed.  Or have I misunderstood ?

Comment: That code I suggested earlier builds a function `f` where `f[a,b]` gives `True` if `a->b` is an edge in the graph indices that were passed to `g`. I think I misunderstood your question in those earlier comments.

Comment: Actually, no it doesn't, it builds a function `f[x]` that gives `True` if `x[[a]]==x[[b]]` for any edge `a->b` in the graph. No coffee yet this morning!

Comment: Mark: I just need (1). Michael: actually it checks if x[a]==x[b] instead of x[[a]]==x[[b]], that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something. When nothing else is working, `Hold` and rules can usually get the job done. I'm not sure it produces the correct results w.r.t. your graph-coloring question but hopefully gives you a starting place. I ended up using `Slot` instead of named variable because there were some scoping issues (also present in my previous suggestion, `x$` vs. `x`) when I used a named variable that I didn't spend the time trying to work around.

```
g[edges_] := 
 With[{ors = (Hold @@ edges) /. {a_, b_} :> #[[a]] == #[[b]]},
  Function[!ors] /. Hold -> Or
  ]

In[90]:= f = g[GraphData[{"Path", 3}, "EdgeIndices"]]
Out[90]= !(#1[[1]] == #1[[2]] || #1[[2]] == #1[[3]]) &

In[91]:= f[{1, 2, 3}]
Out[91]= True

In[92]:= f[{1, 1, 2}]
Out[92]= False
```

I feel like it lacks typical Mathematica elegance, but it works. I'll update if I'm inspired with something more beautiful.

Comment: Yes, that works, but the "lack of typical elegance" is why I keep coming back to this question. Using Part and just ignoring the warnings also seems to work and also gives the most concise code. I wonder if I should just Off[Part] and stop worrying about the warnings

Comment: Instead of turning them off completely, you can wrap your builder code in `Quiet[..., Part::partd]` to suppress them at evaluation time but leave them on elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple other solutions to this kind of problem which don't require you to use `Hold` or `ReleaseHold`, but instead rely on the fact that `Function` already has the `HoldAll` attribute. You first locally "erase" the definitions of `Part` using `Block`, so the expression you're interested in can be safely constructed, and then uses `With` to interpolate that into a `Function` which can then be safely returned outside of the `Block`, and also uses the fact that `Slot` doesn't really mean anything outside of `Function`.

Using your example:

```
coloringChecker[edges_List] := 
 Block[{Part},
  With[{body = And @@ Table[#[[First@edge]] != #[[Last@edge]], {edge, edges}]},
   body &]]
```

I don't know if this is all that much less cumbersome than using `Hold`, but it is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still puzzled by the difficulties that you seem to be having.  Here's a function which checks that no 2 consecutive elements in a list are identical:

```
f[l_List] := Length[Split[l]] == Length[l]
```

No trouble with Part, no error messages for the simple examples I've tried so far including OP's 'test' cases.  I also contend that this is more concise and more readable than either of the other approaches seen so far.

Comment: The goal is to make function g that automatically generates function f for arbitrary graph, not making function f by hand