# Dealing with subscripted variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I define the following (bad) pattern

```
Subscript[\[Beta], i_][x_] := Subscript[\[Beta], i][x[[i]]];
```

1. Is it possible to clear this pattern without clearing definitions for all the other subscripted variables? My first thought would be to modify Subscript's DownValues, but it seems to be empty
2. Is it possible/practical to have functions with subscripted arguments? IE, something along the lines of `f[x_1,x_2,x_3]:=Total[x_#&/@Range[3]]`. I've heard people use `Symbolize` to help with subscripts, would it work here?

Comment: You're example in 2 is not very clear... but yes you can use subscripts in functions -- they obey the pattern matching rules like anything else. And yes, I've often used `Symbolize` or `MakeBoxes` if I want to use a subscript heavy notation.

Comment: The advantage of not using subscript is that for upvalue definitions the symbol is one level less deep. Compare: `b/:a[b[j_],x_]:=x^b[j]` which works fine with `b/:Subscript[a, b[j_]][x_]:=x^b[j]` which fails.

Comment: The goal of f in the example is to have a function which sums over it's arguments, and the question would be how to make it fill x_3 variables with values. Right now I do something along the lines of `f=Function@@{Table[Symbol["x"<>ToString[i]]',{i,1,5},Total...}` for this kind of task

Comment: I still don't follow... I assume you want more than just a alias like `f = Total[{##}]&` -- so you don't mean something like `f[pat:(Subscript[x_, _]..)] := Total[{pat}]` which sums over arguments if they are subscripts of the same symbol...

Comment: Here's an actual practical example -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142730/programmatically-creating-multivariate-functions-in-mathematica  . The solution there uses "Part" and some holding rules to simulate having an array of variables, but it might be easier to have array of subscripted variables instead. Essentially to have a function in terms of x_i variables instead of x[[i]] variables (the latter generates warnings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in `SubValues` (see `Information["*Values"]`).

```
In[25]:= Subscript[\[Beta],i_][x_]:=Subscript[\[Beta],i][x[[i]]];
SubValues[Subscript]
Out[26]= {HoldPattern[Subscript[\[Beta], i_][x_]]:>Subscript[\[Beta], i][x[[i]]]}
```

Just use `=.` to clear:

```
In[27]:= Subscript[\[Beta],i_][x_]=.
SubValues[Subscript]
Out[28]= {}
```

HTH

Comment: Had a hard time finding docs for `=.`: Turns out it is an alias for `Unset`, and a nice one at that :)

Comment: Cool. This generalizes if you want to remove all definitions with say `Subscript[a, _]` to something like `SubValues[Subscript]=Cases[SubValues[Subscript],_?(FreeQ[#,Subscript[a, _]]&)]`.

Comment: Interesting, they are not in Help Browser, but I found a page with explanation for undocumented value lists -- http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html

Comment: @Yaroslaw: To be fair, the `SubValues` do show up if you just use `??` (i.e. `Information`), but I agree that it took some detective work to find out what they were. You could argue that this is an implementation detail: after all, you don't need to know that it is a `SubValue` to `Unset` it.